# Generate random but static test data

Tags: java, testing

When designing test cases, I want to be able to use data that is random but static.

If I use data that is not random, then I will use trivial examples that are representative of the data I expect, rather than the data I have guarded against in my code. For example, if my code is expecting a string with a max length of 15 characters then I would rather specify these constraints and have the data generated for me, within those constraints, rather than some arbitrary example which may be, due to my expectations, within a more strict set of constraints.

If I use data that is not static, then my tests won't be repeatable. It is no good using a string that changes every time the test is run f the test then fails occasionally. It would be much better to use a consistent string and then specify more constraints upon how that string is generated (and obviously make the same checks in my code), if and when a bug is found.

Is this a good strategy for test data?

If so, then I know how to achieve both of these goals independently. For static, but non-random data I just enter something arbitrary e.g. `foo`. For something random but not static, I just use apache random utils e.g. `randomString(5)`. How can I get both?

Note that when data must be unique, it would also be handy to have some way to specify that two pieces of generated data must be distinct. Randomness does this most of the time but cannot be relied upon, obviously, without having unreliable tests!

TL;DR: How can I specify the type of data I want to generate, without having randomised generated data?

Answer (score 2):

What you are describing is property based testing - the best known example being Haskell's quickcheck.

http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Introduction_to_QuickCheck1

There have been a number of java ports such as

- https://bitbucket.org/blob79/quickcheck
- https://github.com/kjw/supercheck
- https://github.com/pholser/junit-quickcheck

The Quickcheck philosophy emphasises the use of random data, but most (all?) of the java ports allow you to set a fixed seed so that the generated values are repeatable.

I've never got round to actually trying this approach, but I would hope it would make your tests more readable (rather than less readable as piotrek suggests), by separating the values from the tests.

If knowledge of the values is important to understand the test/SUT behavior then it is the wrong approach.

Answer (score 1):

Use a random with a constant seed. You can use the [Random(long seed)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#Random%28long%29) constructor for it.

The [RandomStringUtils.random()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/RandomStringUtils.html#random%28int,%20int,%20int,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20char%5B%5D,%20java.util.Random%29) method can accept a `Random` source, which you could have created with a constant seed as described.

Using a constant seed is very useful for making experiments reproduceable - and using them is a very good practice, IMO.

Comment: This sounds great. If I suspected that my data was causing tests to succeed arbitrarily, I could also easily alter the seed temporarily and switch it back again to get different sets of consistent data.

Does it matter what I choose for the seed? Will 1L do?

Is there any way to pick a seed that doesn't result in duplicates or otherwise ensure that duplicates do not occur (should uniqueness be a criteria required)?

Comment: @RupertMadden-Abbott It does not really matters which seed you chose, different seeds will produce different pseudo-random numbers, but it does not matter what seed is used.

Answer (score 0):

don't do it. it gives you a headache, makes your tests unreadable and gives you no benefit. you already see the problems: specification of constraints. so let's go to the imaginary benefits. you worry about that manually you provide  more constrained data then random data. but you want to use same data every time (same seed). so how do you know that random data are better than your manually provided data? how do you know that you chose seed properly? if you are not sure if your test data are good enough then:

- simplify your code (extract methods/classes, avoid ifs, avoid nulls, be more immutable and functional)
- look at edge cases and include them in your tests
- look at generated data and check if some of them differs from what you were thinking of and add those data to your tests
- use mutation testing
- whenever a bug is discovered dufing development, uat or production, add those data to your tests
- do truly random (not repetitive), long running tests. every generated data that breaks the tests should be logged and add to your deterministic unit tests.

by pretending to use random data you just lie to yourself. the data is not random, you don't control it and it makes you stop thinking about edge cases of your code. so don't do it, face the truth and make your tests readable and check more conditions

Answer (score 0):

[Instancio](https://www.instancio.org) is a data generation library for unit tests that does what you are looking. E.g. if you need a random string of certain length:

```java
Foo foo = Instancio.of(Foo.class)
  .generate(field("fooString"), gen -> gen.string().length(10))
  .create();
```

To generate a random predictable values, you can supply a seed:

```java
Foo foo = Instancio.of(Foo.class)
  .generate(field("fooString"), gen -> gen.string().length(10))
  .withSeed(123)
  .create();
```

Or if you use JUnit 5:

```java
@ExtendWith(InstancioExtension.class)
class ExampleTest{

    @Seed(1234)
    @Test
    void example {
        Foo foo = Instancio.of(Foo.class)
           .generate(field("fooString"), gen -> gen.string().length(10))
           .create();
        // ...
    }
}
```

If you need predictable data *always*, you can configure a global seed value through a properties file. This way you won't need to specify it in the code.

https://github.com/instancio/instancio/